# error The GridView 'GridView1' fired event Sorting which wasn't handled

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to Create two groups In  Data Grid like this example http://www.agrinei.com/gridviewhelper/gridviewhelper_en.htm
but there are an error and I don't know what is the reason or how to solve it 
[image]

Comment: Exception says it all. You need to handle the `Sorting` event of the gridview. [Here is example how to do it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorting event seems not handled properly here.
You can handle it in following manner

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" 
  OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting"> 
</asp:GridView>
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{ 
    dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression ;
    GridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the gridview sorting event bind your gridview again

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```